# Retrieve list of prefixed forms in POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I am creating a list of forms, each form gets passed a [prefix arg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms). In my case the prefix arg is a dynamic value (in addition to that each form needs some additional kwargs during initialisation), e.g.

```
for staff in stafflist:
    form = forms.BookingForm(
                prefix=staff.pk, event=event, type=type)
```

so in order to recreate the forms for a POST request I need to store the prefix values inside the Session. This allows me to do the following:

```
staff_list = request.session['staff_list_on_view']
    for staff in stafflist:
        post_forms_dict[staff.id] = forms.BookingForm(
            request.POST, prefix=staff.pk, event=event, type=type)

if all([form.is_valid() for form in post_forms_dict.values()]):
    for form in post_forms_dict.values():
        form.save()
```

This all works fine, but I was wondering if there was a better way than storing the prefix values inside the Session (which I generally like to avoid). Is Django able to return a list of prefixed forms on its own without me having to recreate them by using the prefix again (and having to remember it)? Something like request.POST.get_prefixed_data_as dict() would be nice ;)

Note: I was looking into formsets but I believe I would not be able to use them due to the dynamic kwargs I need to set for each individual form.

Comment: Are you generating the form in a different location(module) from the code that validates it ?

Comment: No - but the problem is not the validation. I am trying to create prefixed forms from post data where the prefixes are only known at runtime.